# Add/remove JFXPanel on Swing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2, layout-manager, event-dispatch-thread

I want to add and remove `JFXPanel` on `JFrame` container but not able to do that. I am stuck here and get no proper solution on button click I want to add and remove the `JFXPanel`  control.

What is the wrong in this code?

```
  public class abc extends JFrame
  {
  JFXPanel fxpanel;
  Container cp;
  public abc()
  {
  cp=this.getContentPane();
  cp.setLayout(null);
  JButton b1= new JButton("Ok");
  JButton b2= new JButton("hide");
  cp.add(b1);
  cp.add(b2);
  b1.setBounds(20,50,50,50);
  b2.setBounds(70,50,50,50);
  b1.addActionListener(this);
  b2.addActionListener(this);
  fxpanel= new JFXPanel();
  cp.add(fxpanel);
  fxpanel.setBounds(600,200,400,500);
 }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
 { 
 if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("OK"))
  {
    fxpanel= new JFXPanel();
    cp.add(fxpanel);
    fxpanel.setBounds(600,200,400,500);


   }
  if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("hide"))
   { 
    cp.remove(fxpanel);
    }
   }
    public static void main(String args[])
   {

      abc f1= new abc();
      f1.show();
    }
   }
```

Comment: what is the wrong in this code

Comment: `cp.setLayout(null);`  Use layouts.  For 'adding and removing things', see [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Dont extend `JFrame` call unnecessarily
- Dont use `null`/`Absolute` `LayoutManager`
- why use `show()` to set `JFrame` visible? you should be using `setVisible(true)`
- Dont forget Swing components should be created a manipulated on  `Event Dispatch Thread` via `SwingUtilities.invokeXXX` and JavaFX components via `Platform.runLater()`

Besides the above the biggest problem you have is that you dont refresh GUI/container after adding/removing components,thus no changes are shown.:

call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on `JFrame` instance to reflect changes after adding/removing components from a visible container.